# Upload photos with php without reload

Tags: php, javascript, image, upload, media

**What I want**

I want to upload a file without reloading the page, also I want to add the source link for the image to the textarea.

So when I push the `upload_photo`, the image uploads and a `link` is added to the `textarea`.

I want pure HTML, Javascript|AJAX and PHP.

---

**What I have**

---

```
<form action"index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="textarea" name="text"></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="photo" />
        <input type="submit" name="upload_photo"/>
    <input type="submit" name="post"/>
</form>
```

**Example sites:**

---

http://www.friendfeed.com - the page don't reloads when you upload the files

**What I don't want**

---

Please avoid posting solutions with jQuery or **any** library, API.

Comment: Without a page refresh I do not believe it is possible without Flash, Java or AJAX. That is as far as I know. Good luck finding a solution though!  And what are these AJAX security risks you are talking about? It is just as secure as using POST...as that is what it generally uses.

Comment: I hear they teach solution to this in Hogwart's

Comment: Ok I edited my question, don't eat me because of AJAX :D as I said "as I know", that's why I came here to know how can I make it :), I love AJAX and it's fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy.
Put an iframe, give it a name, for example "MyIframe".
Then in the form, add the TARGET attribute, with the value "MyIframe", and the action - the script that takes the upload (takeupload.php for example)
In the main page define a Javascript function that does something you need after the upload is done, which will be called, with parameters, from the page generated by takeupload.php.

in takeupload.php upload the image, then send as an output a normal blank HTML page that will execute a script which will call the method described above, with a set of parameters you need (image name, path, error, or plain HTML to insert somewhere, etc.).

use it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.YourJSMethod(parameters);
</script>
```

The page will be loaded in the iframe, and it will run a function defined outside the iframe. Upload is done, and the parent page receives data about the result.

This is fairly simple. No jQuery needed, no AJAX, no nothing, just a very simple Javascript code and a little HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This **can** indeed be done with AJAX. I don't think that using AJAX is any more of a security risk than sending a vanilla HTML form; you will have to validate all user input on the server side all the same.  Here's a simple example:

http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html